# Kubernetes - how to send request to all the minions?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos

I have pod and its purpose is to take the incoming data and write it to the host volume. I'm running this pod in all the minions.

Now when i setup NodePort service to this pods, traffic will go to 1 pod at a time.

But how do i send request to all this pods in different minions? How to i bypass the load-balancing here? I want that data to be available in all the minions host volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a [hostPort for the container](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_containerport) and address each pod on each node individually via the host IP.

See caveats in the best-practice guide's [Services section](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/config-best-practices/#services).

Answer (score 1):

A service uses a selector to identify the list of pods to proxy to (if they're in the Ready state). You could simply ask for the same list of pods with a GET request:

```
$ curl -G "$MASTER/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/pods?labelSelector=$KEY=$VALUE"
```

And then manually send your request to each of the pod `ip:port` endpoints. If you need to be able to send the request from outside the cluster network, you could create a proxy pod (exposed to the external network through the standard means). The proxy pod could watch for pods with your label (similar to above), and forward any requests it receives to the list of ready pods.

A similar effect could be achieved using `hostPort` and forwarding to nodes, but the use of hostPort is discourage (see [best practices](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/config-best-practices/#services)).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that works as long as you can send the requests from a container inside the k8s network (this may not match the OP's desire exactly, but I'm guessing this may work for someone googling this).

You have to look up the pods somehow. Here I'm finding all pods in the `staging` namespace with the label `app=hot-app`:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=hot-app -n staging -o json | jq -r '.items[].status.podIP'
```

this example uses the awesome jq tool to parse the resulting json and grab the pod ips, but you can parse the json in other ways, including with kubectl itself.

this returns something like this:

```
10.245.4.253
10.245.21.143
```

you can find the internal port like this (example has just one container, so one unique port):

```
kubectl get pods -l app=hot-app -n staging -o json | jq -r '.items[].spec.containers[].ports[].containerPort' | sort | uniq
8080
```

then you get inside a container in your k8s cluster with curl, combine the ips and port from the previous commands, and hit the pods like this:

```
curl 10.245.4.253:8080/hot-path
curl 10.245.21.143:8080/hot-path
```